# Android Galaxy S3 - Low Memory

Tags: javascript, android, upload, samsung-mobile

I'm using the Android S3 and using it for some file upload purposes.

I am trying to use a js library called dropzone.js(http://www.dropzonejs.com/) They have a function to drag and drop and also a old school file upload as well.

When I use this plugin and trying the demo, I get an error on my S3 saying "Unable to complete previous operation do to low memory". This happens on the Android browser and on Google Chrome on the S3. The result is that I cannnot upload my image and on the Android Browser I get redirected to my homepage and on Chrome the page refreshes.

If you had this "Unable to complete precious operation do to low memory" please let me know of any solution.

ALSO! I just tried this on facebook's upload and it also does not work and shows this same error. So it's probably not a dropzone issue, but an Android issue.

But in any case, if you have some solutions please let me know! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what happened to the phone, but I did a factory reset and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my galaxy ace and just figured out.

- I have ticked off "Do not keep activities" check box in "Developer options".

It solved the issue. That's all.

Comment: That's not all, not even close. Unchecking "do not keep activities" does not fix the issue, it might only make it less probably to occur (perhaps significantly, perhaps even to the point that it never happened to you any more). With the option checked, you're guaranteed to suffer from the issue. With it unchecked, you have no guarantee, it may happen randomly at any time. I observe the issue all the time, and I do not have "don't keep activities" checked.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with my samsung galaxy s3 phone and google chrome browser.

Unchecking "do not keep activities" does not solve the problem for me.I download and install firefox, the issue does not happen in firefox...

I don't know about chrome browser!

Answer (score -2):

I have had the same problem on my Samsung Galaxy s4. I have found the solution on my phone and I have had no issues since. 1. Go to the Settings on your phone. 2. Select More in the top right task item. 3. Scroll to Developer Options. - If you don`t have developer options enabled follow steps 1 & 2, Then scroll down to about device and click on it. The phone informarion should be displayed and you should scroll down till you get to Build Number. The next thing to do is click on Build Number several times... ( Eaxh time you click on it an info bar will be displayed telling you how many clicks are needed for Developer options. When you have clicked BN several times then DO will now be opwn and we can continue with the above. 4. If you have clicked into Developer Options sucessfully then you must scroll down to the apps options near the bottom of D.O menu. 5. If ( Do not keep activities) is selected then be sure to untick it making sure the box has no tick in it as it will end every app or running operation as soon as it leaves the page, Hence the reason photos wont load up to Facebook etc. If this is done correctly then you should now be able to upload photos.

Read more: Unable to complete previous operation due to low memory? - When i tried to upload a photo from gallery to facebook using google chrome i got failed showing msg failed due to low memory wahat is solution :: Ask Me Fast at http://www.askmefast.com/Unable_to_complete_previous_operation_due_to_low_memory-qna7160577.html